# Почему не работает overflow-y auto Ipad?

Tags: css

Привет!
Почему-то не работает скролл  в safari на ipad?

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.goals-select-items {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.goals-select-items {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: auto;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: red;
}

.goals-list-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.goals-select-items>.goals-list-wrapper>ul {
  margin-top: 60px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(40, 43, 62, 0.05);
  font-size: 26px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  background-color: black;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.goals-select-items>.goals-list-wrapper>ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 105px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(40, 43, 62, 0.05);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="goals-select-items">
  <div class="goals-list-wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/"><span>plan for my retirement</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="/"><span>save for my children’s education</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="/"><span>get coverage for medical expenses</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="/"><span>grow my wealth</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="/"><span>learn about insurance</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="/"><span>learn about investing</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: На iphone работает, значит и на ipad должно также работать

Comment: @Cheg но вот на айпеде не работает. На айфоне да, проблемы нет.